How can I copy all files from C: on Windows to a drive attached to a Mac?
I want to copy all files on the C: drive on a Windows 10 PC to an external drive on a Mac running Mac Sonoma 14.2.1. The Windows computer was owned by a recently deceased family member, and my goal is simply to copy everything so that we can go through it later. I know that lots of the files will be useless on the Mac (e.g., executables), but I also know that Windows programs store data file all over the place, so I want to copy everything to avoid missing anything.
With both computers on the network, I tried copying everything from the Windows side (i.e., telling Windows to copy everything on C: to a Mac on the same network). That failed, with Windows telling me "You don't have permission to copy files to this location over the network" (as in this question).
I also tried copying everything from the Mac side (i.e., telling the Mac Finder to copy everything in C:\Users on the Windows machine (because the Mac didn't seem to have a way to mount the entire C: drive) to an external drive on the Mac), but the Finder told me, "The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -8058)."
I've googled both error messages, but I didn't see anything that looked like an easy way to get past the problem.
Each machine has only one account on it, and that account has administrative privileges. It's not the same login ID on both machines.
Isn't there a simple way to copy all the files from C: on a Windows machine to a Mac?

You probably want to use a backup tool, if you're trying to create a full copy of ALL of the files, useful or not. That will be the simplest way to do this. On the network, with the computers both running, you need to fix permissions, which is the problem you're facing. But if you take the drive out of the computer and connect it to your Mac using a cradle, AND the drive is not encrypted, you may be able to simply grab the files and copy them. Alternatively, on the Mac create a share of the target drive, access/attach that to the Windows computer, and use a backup tool.

Instead of copying files. Create a VM from the physical machine and access the files within VMWare Fusion or Parallels.

If the Windows drive is not encrypted, make a full disk image, which you can open and browse as if it were one or more drives. There are many third-party tools to do so, such as Macrium Reflect Free (https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html) and alternatives (https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). Most can be run by installing on the Windows PC or by running from "rescue media", e.g., a USB drive.

It might be easier to remove the hard drive/storage and use a USB to SATA adapter to piug the storage device directly into your MAC.
If it is an SSD the USB port should have enough power by itself.  If it is a hard drive then you need one with an external power supply.

I'm in the process of doing this, but it's taking forever. First the Mac said the copying would take about 17 hours. Then a day. Then two days. Now it says three days. This is over a USB 3 connection. The total to be copied is about 245GB. This looks like it will work, but I wouldn't call it practical.

@KnowItAllWannabe Depending on the age of the system this could indicated the hard drive is in bad shape.  Not all USB to SATA adapters are of equal quality.  You would need to use software like smartctl to read the SMART data from the drive to check on the drives general health.  How long did you let the copy runs?  These estimates can be off wildly.

"Off wildly" pretty much nails it. The estimated copy time increased to four days and then five, but a few hours, the operation finished.
